# How to encode hexadecimal code to string using ISO-8859-6 charset?

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, binary, ascii

I know there are other threads that answer this problem but for me, it is a little different.

I have many binary files containing different types of data that need to be shown(ASCII, hex ..).

So my usual method of displaying ASCII values is using the ISO-8859-1 included in StandardCharsets class. Sadly it doesn't support natively iso-8859.6 need to display Arabic characters.
Here are my methods used for encoding:

First method gives me Hex codes as String:

```
public static String hexField(byte[] record, int offset, int length) {
     StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(length * 2);
     int end = offset + length;

     for (int i = offset; i < end; i++) {
         int high_nibble = (record[i] & 0xf0) >>> 4;
         int low_nibble = (record[i] & 0x0f);
         s.append(hex_table[high_nibble]);
         s.append(hex_table[low_nibble]);
         
     }

     return s.toString();
}
```

Second method: Displays the ASCII field using the previous method:

```
private static String asciiField(byte[] record, int offset, int length) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String field = hexField(record, offset, length) ; 
    
    byte[] fieldByte = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(field);
    return new String(fieldByte,StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1).trim() ;
}
```

How can I display Arabic characters encoded in iso-8859.6 Thank you !

Comment: There seems to be some confusion: ASCII values are ASCII values. ISO-8859-*x* values are ISO-8859-*x* values. While there *is* overlap (specifically the ISO encodings are a superset of the ASCII codec) as soon as you involve ISO-8859-1 (or -6) you no longer need to talk about ASCII at all. Additionally your `asciiField` method quite unnecessarily converts the `byte[]` to a hex representation and that hex representation back into a `byte[]` for no apparent value.

Comment: You are actually right ! It was a quick fix at the moment that needs to be looked at. Thank you for pointing it out to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While ISO-8859-6 is not *required* to be supported by the Java SE standard (and as such doesn't have a corresponding constant in `StandardCharsets`), I believe it is widely supported.

To use it, simply use the String constant `"ISO-8859-6"` where a character set is required, for example to convert a `byte[]` containing ISO-8859-6 data to a `String`, simply use

```
byte[] byteData = {(byte) 0xC2, (byte) 0xD4, (byte) 0xD8};
String s = new String(byteData, "ISO-8859-6");
```

This works on my machine just fine. (the `byteData` in that example almost certainly contains gibberish, since I don't know any Arabic, but it *does* represent some Arabic characters in ISO-8859-6).

Alternatively you can use `Charset.forName("ISO-8859-6")` if you want an actual `Charset` object at hand. Doing that also moves the `UnsupportedEncodingException` to the place where `Charset.forName` is called and doesn't litter every `byte[]`-to-`String` conversion place with that exception.

Also please note that `hexField` seems to do the exact opposite of `parseHexBinary` so those two methods chained together like that are a pointless `byte[]`->hex representation->`byte[]` conversion chain. There is even a `String` constructor that takes an offset and length that you could use:

```
private static final Charset ISO_8859_6 = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-6");

private static String textField(byte[] record, int offset, int length) {
    return new String(record, offset, length, ISO_8859_6).trim() ;
}
```

Comment: I apologize for the late reply. The solution provided gave me "???". I'll look further into it! Thank you sir

Comment: @ZiedOrabi: note that `???` could indicate that wherever you *output to* doesn't support the characters. Try to dump the individual Unicode codepoints of the resulting string and check if they are anything other than 63/0x3F (which would be `?`).

Comment: \u622\u634\u638 . I just googled those Unicodes and they are definitely Arabic letters. It could be a problem with the console when printing. My main goal is to fill an excel file with Arabic content from a binary file. I'll try to check if I can modify the charset on the excel file. As for this question, your answer clearly is valid and the rest Is my work. Thank you very much !

Comment: Just in case you were curious. I fixed it by adding this line.
  String[] word = s1.split("\\\\");
     for (int i = 0 ; i<word.length ; i++) { 
      System.out.println(word[i]); 
     }